# Greedy algorithm error using c++ sets

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, greedy

I've created  a greedy algorithm to solve a problem (homework assignment) and since I'm learning `c++` I would like to achieve the same thing but using `sets`.

Basically we submit the homework to an online platform, this platform as some test cases that we don't know of, and we get a score based on that. If we pass all test cases we have 100%;

The problem is like this.

We have an actor that wants to schedule appointments with the fans that answered an online questionnaire about him. Now he wants to choose the fan's that maximizes the sum of points in the questionnaire and respecting the fan's availability. He can see only one fan a day.

We have an input like this:

```
6
1 1 5  
2 2 4
3 1 2
4 3 1
5 1 6
6 2 2
```

Where the first line is the number of fans and following, in each line, we have the fan id, the fan available days and the fan points achieved in the online questionnaire. I must print the ids of the fans that the actor will see and the sum of combined points of the fans. So for the above input I have the following output:

```
2
4
5
11
```

Note that if two fans have the same points, the fan prefered should be the one with the lower ID.

I've started by sorting the fans by the points of the questionnaire (decreasing order) and then by the lower id.
When reading the input, I'm adding the number of days to a `set`.
My idea was like this:

When iterating over the data, I check if the fan in study days available is in the `set`. If it is, add this fan and remove the days from the set. If the fan days is not in the set, then get the `upper_bound` and decrease the iterator to set the fan on the first day lower that the initial day. The algorithm stops wen the set is empty or I iterate all over the fans.

Here is my greedy function:

```
void greedy() {
    fan_id.insert(questionnaire_result[0][0]);
    days_available.erase(questionnaire_result[0][1]);
    total_questionaire_sum += questionnaire_result[0][2];

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < number_of_fans; i++) {
        if (days_available.empty()) {
            break;
        } else if (days_available.count(questionnaire_result[i][1])) {
            fan_id.insert(questionnaire_result[i][0]);
            days_available.erase(questionnaire_result[i][1]);
            total_questionaire_sum += questionnaire_result[i][2];
        } else {
            it = days_available.upper_bound(questionnaire_result[i][1]);
            if (it == days_available.begin()) {
                if (*it < questionnaire_result[i][1]) {
                    fan_id.insert(questionnaire_result[i][0]);
                    days_available.erase(*it);
                    total_questionaire_sum += questionnaire_result[i][2];
                }
            } else if (it == days_available.end()) {
                it--;
                if (*it < questionnaire_result[i][1]) {
                    fan_id.insert(questionnaire_result[i][0]);
                    days_available.erase(*it);
                    total_questionaire_sum += questionnaire_result[i][2];
                }

            } else {
                it--;
                if (*it < questionnaire_result[i][1]) {
                    fan_id.insert(questionnaire_result[i][0]);
                    days_available.erase(*it);
                    total_questionaire_sum += questionnaire_result[i][2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe my problem is in this line:

```
it = days_available.upper_bound(questionnaire_result[i][1]);
```

I've tested many possibilities and this is working in all my test cases. Unfortunately, we don't have the test cases of the platform.

Does someone see an situation that my code fails? With this I'm getting 90% of the score.

**EDIT:**

As Edward pointed me out, I've managed to solve the problem like this:

When reading the input added this line of code:

```
max_days = max_days | questionnaire_result[i][1];
```

And then did this:

```
for (int j = 1; j < max_days + 1; j++) {
            days_available.insert(j);
        }
```

Problem solved

Comment: Not the answer but code in `else if (it == days_available.end())` and `else` branches is identical, so `else if` branch can be removed.

Comment: Yep. You're right. It gives me the exact same points

Comment: Should fans in the output be sorted by id, or by their appointments?

Comment: Since I want to maximize the points, it should be sorted by the score in the questionnaire

Comment: Sorting of the output does not change the amount of points. My question is what does the online platform accept as valid output. In your example does it accept `2 4 5 11` (sorted by id) or `5 2 4 11` (sorted by appointments)?

Comment: Sorry. It accepts sorted by ID

Comment: @Favolas: is each fan's available days a count of available days or one specific date that the fan is available?

Comment: @Edward imagine the date 1 of April as the date the actor will start meeting with the fans. If a fan as 3 available days it means that she can meet with the actor in 1, 2 and 3th of April.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This input file will cause the program to generate an incorrect result:

```
2
1 2 6
2 2 5
```

Both fans are available either day, so it's clear that both fans could be visited and the total output score should be 11.  Your algorithm, however, only chooses the first one and outputs a score of 6.

Comment: Many many thanks. With your example I understood what I was doing wrong and now managed to solve the problem. Edited my question to include the solution. Thanks once again